# JQuery select browser doesn't update

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a simple jquery select issue using Query Mobile that I have googled for and the answers I've found just aren't working. I have an html select as follows:

```
<select name=x id=Sel>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">3</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

I read the actual value from a database using an ajax call and then execute the line:

```
$("#Sel").val(result);
```

The screen still shows 1 as selected. I have verified that immediately before this line that result is equal to 2.

I know I've seen this somewhere, just can't remember where.

Comment: What browser are you using that it is not working in? I made a fiddle that seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/wpcqn4e0/1/

Comment: My bet is result is not what you think it is `console.log(escape(result));`

Comment: @k-nut I have tested in both FF and Chrome. I can make it work the way you did it also. The problem is that this happens long after the Ready() function has fired. It only seems to happen when I am trying to update with the results of an ajax call to get the value from a database after the user has selected an option. I have verified with a $("#Sel").val() call that the value of #Sel is correctly set to 2. However, the screen is still showing 1. I didn't mention that I am using JQM which could be causing a problem. I will edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: @epascarello See my comment, just did that.

Comment: do you think you can try to reproduce this in a fiddle

Comment: So you are using selectMenu?

Comment: @epascarello Negative.

Comment: Please post your full code, when do you create it? Are you using JQM events?

Comment: @Omar Figured out the issue while I was doing just that on jsFiddle. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **[refresh](http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh)** the jQM selectmenu widget after changing the value:

```
$("#Sel").val(2).selectmenu("refresh");
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/wtfxxd5y/2/)**

Comment: I had already tried that. When I do I get the error: Error: cannot call methods on selectmenu prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'
 

...urn!1;return!0},error:function(e){throw Error(e)},parseHTML:function(e,t,n){if(!... --> I add a $("#editUserPlan").selectmenu() statement in my ready() code and it messes up the formatting of the select statement and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Found the error. I just took over this code and should have checked around it. The enclosing DIV had the same ID as the <select> (a very good reason NOT to use ID selectors). I'll accept your answer since it was the correct answer for my question.